# Finding stores with more than 10 employees in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Given I have Table `stores_employees` which has two columns:

```
store_id, employee_id
```

How can I find the store which has more than 10 employees? What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: If this question was harder you would not have answers but people asking you what have you tried like John, but easy points will get you this quick answers. In the future try to post what have you tried or read about it at least.

Comment: Agree with @Luis, -1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

You will use an aggregate function in a `HAVING` clause and `GROUP BY store_id`

```
select store_id
from stores_employees 
group by store_id
having count(employee_id) > 10
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/641f2/1)

If you want to include the total employees, then you can use:

```
select store_id, count(employee_id) TotalEmployees
from stores_employees 
group by store_id
having count(employee_id) > 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT store_id, count(employee_id) FROM stores_employees GROUP BY store_id
HAVING COUNT(employee_id) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of the question logically you need to count instances of store_id and employee_id from the stores_emloyees table where count is > 10.

Just play around with the commands to see which one shows the desired result.I found this the most effective way to learn mysql rather than copying from a website.

Keywords you might use:

```
SELECT
FROM
ORDER BY
BETWEEN
```